# How to know which program is being broadcast?

Tags: android, datetime, android-recyclerview

I have been meeting a problem that is how to detect which program TV show is being broadcast. I have a list of item that contain time table for each program TV show. My JSONObject look like this:

```
"Title": "Breaking news",
    "Description": " ",
    "Avatar": "",
    "VideoId": 0,
    "ShowOnSchedule": false,
    "ScheduleTime": "2016-04-05T03:00:00",
    "ChannelId": 1,
    "ZoneVideoId": 0,
    "Invisibled": null,
    "ZoneName": null,
    "ZoneUrl": null,
    "RowIndex": 10,
    "Url": null,
    "share_url": null,
    "thumb": null
```

My problem is for example. When the device's time is `15:03:00`, and my program starts from `15:00:00` to `15:30:00`. How can I detect this program TV show is being broadcast?, if device's time is between `15:00:00` and `15:30:00` that's mean program TV show is being broadcast. I tried some code below, but what I received just time greater and less than device's time.

```
 Model model = arrayList.get(position);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        Log.i("getCurrent", String.valueOf(formattedDate));
        Date currentDate = formatter.parse(formattedDate);
        int difference = currentDate.compareTo(formatter.parse(lichChieuModel.getScheduleTime()));
        if(difference == 0){
    Log.i("getTAG", "Same Time");
    }else if(difference < 0){

     Log.i("getTag", "Less Than");
    }else{
     Log.i("getTAg", "Greater Than");
    }
```